# How to remove Materialize Floating Action Button animation?

Tags: css, animation, materialize, floating-action-button

I've created a [Floating Action Button](https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html) with [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/), but the animation to show the options when you hover over the button takes too long.

I've searched on Google and looked in the Materialize documentation for FABs, but I can't find any way to remove the transition or decrease the duration of it. These are the only options:

> ```
> | Name           | Type    | Default | Description                                                       |
> |----------------|---------|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
> | direction      | String  | 'top'   | Direction FAB menu opens. Can be 'top', 'right', 'buttom', 'left' |
> | hoverEnabled   | Boolean | true    | If true, FAB menu will open on hover instead of click             |
> | toolbarEnabled | Boolean | false   | Enable transit the FAB into a toolbar on click                    |
> ```

There's another option to show the options when you click instead of when you hover by adding the `click-to-toggle` class, but this still has the animation.

**How can I remove the animation?**

<sup>(Decreasing the duration is acceptable as well)</sup>

Here's a StackSnippet to demonstrate the animation:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
    var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
    <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(Additionally, if you add the `waves-effect` class to the buttons, the animation goes even slower. I'd like to keep the `waves-effect` class, but that's optional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you downloaded css and js file and loading to your project locally.

You can unminify your js and look for these lines in your unminified js:

```
key: "_animateInFAB",
  value: function() {
    var e = this;
    this.$el.addClass("active");
    var i = 0;
    this.$floatingBtnsReverse.each(function(t) {
      s({
          targets: t,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: [.4, 1],
          translateY: [e.offsetY, 0],
          translateX: [e.offsetX, 0],
          duration: 275, //this is duration in ms for opening fab.
          delay: i,
          easing: "easeInOutQuad"
      }), i += 40
    })
}
```

and once you found these lines, change duration as you wish, but this will effect only opening duration. Few lines down, you can see similar code for closing. I worked with Materialize long time ago and I made that kind of modifications in code. I hope this can help you.